# boost::asio::read_until not reliable

Tags: c++, sockets, boost

I'm trying to implement a client/server using **boost::asio::read_until**.
read_until is pretty good for my messaging.

However, when I tested client and server in various situations, I found
that read_until returns before delimiter detected on high traffic.

When sending 160000 bytes in a loop, sooner or later read_until returns with less
bytes transferred.

This happens not, if for instance, sending size is 16384 bytes or less in a loop.

My implementation is pretty simple.

```
// sender:
std::size_t bytes_out=boost::asio::write(socket(), boost::asio::buffer(msg, len),
            boost::asio::transfer_all(), ignored_error);
assert(bytes_out==160000);

// receiver:
boost::asio::streambuf b;
std::size_t bytes_transferred = boost::asio::read_until(socket(), b,    
 delim);
assert(bytes_transferred ==160000);
```

On sending side, i asserted that that bytes sent=160000. I got not one assertion. However, on receiver side, sooner or later less bytes returned by read_until
than sended.

The delim is 0 and i made sure that no 0 contained in the message (for instance
sending 160000 'a').

This all been tested on a windows vm.

I'm not an expert, perhaps there is a limit somewhere under the hood (tcp stack,etc.). 
Or is there a limit with boost socket ?

Thank you for comments.

Comment: Is this your very first read operation on this connection? Otherwise, most likely, some of those 160,000 bytes were consumed by a previous `read` or `read_until`. If you check the docs for `read_until`, you'll see it's explicitly permitted to read *past* the delimiter.

Comment: Thank you,  past limiter and i use bytes_transferred to pick intended bytes. Also, i get less than expected so NOT until limiter. And this happens sooner or later, so not with first bytes. In my tests, i already restart server and client.

Comment: Can you show us more code? Does this ever happen with a connection's very first read?

Comment: Following a small server and client cpp derived from boost samples.

Comment: It's not a limit. It's most likely your sender and receiver getting out of sync.

Comment: get files here: http://www.filedropper.com/boosttcpserver and http://www.filedropper.com/boosttcpclient  i linked to boost161, static, static runtime, vs2015, debug 64

Comment: It's hard to match your question to your code. Your code send 160,001 bytes (160,000 a's followed by a delimiter) but your question contains asserts that 160,000 bytes are sent/received.

Comment: Sorry, let me explain: 160000 contains message + 1 delimiter. read_until reads delimiter included. So minus it, you get 160000. The assert is (received-1)==1600000. However, please check out the code and you will see. It works not reliable.

Comment: I can't see how the code corresponds to your question though. Your question shows assert's on the number of bytes transferred.

Comment: My code sample is excluding the delim. In real code, the delim is included. Sorry for that. However, the equation remains correct and in the real run, the mismatch is not one, as you might assume, it is 100 bytes or more. It differs from to call to call. My simple example demonstrates this.